# Pulling every email job an email address has ever received

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am looking to pull all the email jobs that a particular email address has received. The issue is our transactional unit uses email as a the subscriber key and our promotional unit uses unique subscriber keys.

I am looking to pull, based on the email address, anything that email has gotten regardless of what what the sub key is.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Can you share what you have tried so far in terms of researching a solution? Please take a minute reading few these helpful tips for asking questions: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It will be impossible to retrieve all historical information about sends. The data views you need to connect to get that kind of information have a retention period of about 6 months, so if there was anything sent to your customers before that, you won't be able to retrieve _all_ data.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option would be to use the `_Sent` data view. Because the `_Sent` data view doesn’t have an email address and only subscriber key, you’ll need to join the data with the `_Subscriber` data view. Note that all data views only go back 6 months worth of data so it is not a full history of information.